# Orientdb cluster on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I looked at the video / screenshots at this [location](http://orientdb.com/orientdb-amazon-web-services/) but it talks about running a standalone version of Orientdb. Is there a cloudformation Snippet i can see which would allow me to run a cluster of say 3 Orientdb Nodes with replication. I want to be able to use a EBS volume so that any ephemeral node going down should not be catastrophic.

I rememeber the Orientdb team member mention that they have created an internal division inside the company for AWS but i could not find any resource published for running a highly available cluster on AWS.

Many thanks for any help on this. We are looking at running a production cluster of Orientdb but there is not much information / best practices available on Orientdb site.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm part of the OrientDB team. The OrientDB team is finalizing the distributed-auto scale version of OrientDB on AWS. It will be released in about one month from now. If you want to test OrientDB on AWS, you can install any available image and configure it manually following the instruction on the web site.

Comment: @Lvca The documentation talks about installing a single instance on AWS it does not talk about the Hazelcast configuration and other AWS related nuances. I would appreciate if there is a Cloudformation stack you can share which i can use to create a cluster using the existing Orientdb AMIs.

Comment: Take a look at: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Distributed-Configuration.html#amazon-ec2

Comment: @Lvca Thanks i am aware of the link you shared above. In my case i am using the ECS service from Amazon and have created a task definition with desired count to 3. When i deploy the service the nodes are not able to see each other. I suppose i am doing something wrong in my hazelcast [config](https://gist.github.com/mindnuts/9846120ee2d64a46538f90594951a0e5) file.

Comment: @Lvca Do you have any update on the Distributed-auto scale version on AWS. I could not find any announcement on the orientdb website.

Thanks